# how to sort the result of getAllwindows based on lastFocusedWindow?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

is there any option to sort the result of getAllWindows based on the lastFocused window?

```
chrome.windows.getAll(null, (windows) => {
    /* how to sort the windows absed on lastFocused */
})
```

Comment: A window object has `focused` property which you can use, but it's really not clear what you mean by "based".

Comment: I mean to get a sorted array of windows with sort order lastFocused

Comment: There's only one window that was last focused so to maintain a historical timeline you'll have to implement it yourself by observing chrome.windows.onFocusChanged event and storing the window id and performance.now() in a `Map` variable inside your extension.

Comment: thanks for this answer, but is there any other method other that observing the window focus change? is it possible to sort inside chrome.windows.getAll() using any window object property?

Comment: As you can see in the documentation, there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain focused windows history in an array. and then sort the window item by index in history array:

```js
var focusedWindowHistoty=[];


chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(window) {

    focusedWindowHistoty = focusedWindowHistoty.filter(function(it){
       return it != window;
    });
    focusedWindowHistoty.push(window);
});

chrome.windows.getAll(null, (windows) => {
    var sorted=windows.sort(function(a,b){
       return getIndex(a)>getIndex(b);
    });
})

function getIndex(item){
  var foundIndex=-1;
  focusedWindowHistoty.forEach(function(it,index){
    if(it==item){
      foundIndex=index;
    }
  })
  return foundIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks a good answer. But is it possible to sort with any window Object property?

Comment: using which window property?